# An issue with layout params of relative layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am having an issue with my app, basically i have few layouts like this:
|ABC| 
each letter describe one layout(A is the relative layout).
When i am adding an image view to the relative layout, this image view 
can move over all the layout. But the relative layout became stretched to whole the width of the screen.
|A|
so basically you can`t see the B,C layouts any more.

This is my function:

```
public void startGame(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<currentLevelObs.size();i++){
        if(currentLevelObs.get(i)==Globals.OBS_ENTRY_INDEX)
            break;
    }


    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (i+1));
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i);
    lp.leftMargin = 25;


    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setLayoutParams(lp);
    img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hero);
    gameLayout.addView(img);

}
```

This function called from onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

You have given `layout width` to `fill parent.` So it will take up the whole screen. Thats the problem. Change it to `wrap-content` and then check.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried this solution already
when the image view moving the image is disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Add your `ABC` layouts to a `ScrollView`, that way you can scroll down to see `B` and `C`.

it should be like this:

```
<ScrollView
..
...
....>
<D
..>
A
B
C
</D>
</ScrollView>
```

a ScrollView can contain only 1 child, so keep your `ABC` in a `D` layout which is in `ScrollView`

Comment: The relative layout is set to fixed size. My app reads an obstacle file(locations of all the obstacles of each level) so i can`t use scroll view.